# Fetch from server or client side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

Let me see if I can explain this properly.

I am making a website where users can save some information (In this case movie information).

I am getting all the movie data from a third part API (the movie database).

So I was wondering which of these two scenarios are best performance wise?

1. Send empty views to my client and have a JavaScript fetch the movies from TMD ;
   API on page load and render them on to the page?
2. Fetch the data from TMD API render it into my view and send it to the client?

I assume that the first scenario is the best one for me, since I do not have to fetch any extra data before I send my views to my user (and this way also don't use as much bandwidth).

However I feel like the second scenario makes it easier for me to manipulate the data to how I like and want it with less code as I can just render it onto the views before sending it (This way to I would have to use more bandwidth since I have to fetch some data first, and thus send more data to my client?).

Comment: If you are not concerned about exposing movie apis to user, I think it's just a matter of preference.

Comment: Performance-wise - for you or for your users?

Comment: Ask the third party on how they would like your application access their API. They have costs, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

benefits of each:

### serverside rendering

1) less data has to be sent to the client (filtering)

2) API requests can be cached, especially useful if there are request limits or if heavy computations have to be done

3) Less code at the client

### clientside fetching & rendering

1) dynamic content without reloading (you can just fetch some more data)

2) you don't need a real server. A static fileserver like NGINX will be enough, no programming required at the serverside.

Comment: I never actually thought about caching, that actually sounds like that would be the best way to go. 

Could you point me in the right direction of some caching tutorials?

Should it make any difference, i use Express for my application

Comment: @jakeTheDane https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)

Answer (score 4):

As you've articulated already, there are pros and cons to each approach.

Generally you would use a server-side request if the API credentials are not safe to make public, or if you'll be serving the same content to many clients and want to act as a cache to reduce load on the third-party API. You would also do so for data that you want to process, particularly in a proprietary manner, before serving it to a client, though that's a little more obvious.

Conversely, fetching data on the client is more common when the API request will vary based on user input or client state (e.g. cookies, such as a request to a social media API from a logged in user). The downside of this is that you tend to make many more requests to third-party APIs and you may end up exhausting a rate-limited API, resulting in delays for clients.